# how to get device pixel ratio using flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, padding, margin

as you might know there are two types of size in flutter app (physical,logical).
for margin and padding if we want the app to be responsive we must get context size (width,height).
for a reason I don't want to use MediaQuery.of(context).size so I'm using

```
Size screenSize = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize;
    double width = screenSize.width;
    double height = screenSize.height;
```

in such case the size is physical and can't be used like before for padding and margin with edgeinsets.
what I'm asking is a way to either change physical pixel size to logical without using context and MediaQuery or a way to use physical pixels to give responsive margin and padding.

thanks in advance.

I tried to get the ratio with testing results it differs between devices so we can't use static ratio.
The ratio is not the ratio of height/width of physical size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the screen size without `context` like this:

```
var size = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size;
```

now if you print this `size`, you can see it is equals to the size that you get from `MediaQuery` with `context`.

Comment: Yes it was helpful but i used another similar way using
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).devicePixelRatio
and dividing physical size to that ratio 
ultimately they both work but I think your code is much more better because it uses less code lines thank you!